# Output specific strings from a file in RedHat Linux 7 - Regex possibly

Tags: regex, linux, bash, redhat

First time asking a questions so my apologies if I skipped over some of the basics before posting this question.

Basically my questions is fairly simple....I have a file that gets written to very often and the first string/column always has the word "CLEAR" or "CRITICAL", sometimes "WARNING", but I want to ignore those entries.

Around the 17th column there is a specific32bit alpha-numeric # that accompanies each entry. I'm trying to find a way to, without modifying the original file....write out just the 1st column and the 32bit alpha-numeric # into a new file for starters. Unfortunately the 32bit # is not always in column 17 or else I could do this on my own.

Here is a glance of a portion of the log file that I'm referring to. Please don't bash me to hard on my ignorance if my question is not detailed enough or has already been answered before.

> CLEAR ; lnx20162.csxt.csx.com ; Database Instance ; actd ; Dec 14,
>   2012 4:46:31 PM EST ; D0C53D1FB19075C2E0405C0A6FF002BF ; Metric Alert
>   ; Response:State ; The database status is OPEN.
>
> CRITICAL ; lnx20016.csxt.csx.com ; Database Instance ; GISP_GISP2 ;
>   Dec 14, 2012 4:39:54 PM EST ; D0C53D32C0E53F85E0405C0A6FF002C9 ;
>   Metric Alert ; alertLog:genericErrStack ; ORA-error stack (4,031)
>   logged in
>   /oramisc01/oracle/diag/rdbms/gisp/GISP2/trace/alert_GISP2.log.
>
> CRITICAL ; lnx20016.csxt.csx.com ; Database Instance ; GISP_GISP2 ;
>   Dec 14, 2012 4:40:00 PM EST ; D0C53D32C1093F85E0405C0A6FF002C9 ;
>   Metric Alert ; alertLog:genericErrStack ; ORA-error stack (04031,
>   04031) logged in
>   /oramisc01/oracle/diag/rdbms/gisp/GISP2/trace/alert_GISP2.log.
>
> CRITICAL ; lnx20016.csxt.csx.com ; Database Instance ; GISP_GISP2 ;
>   Dec 14, 2012 4:39:55 PM EST ; D0C53D32C0EB3F85E0405C0A6FF002C9 ;
>   Metric Alert ; alertLog:genericErrStack ; ORA-error stack (04031,
>   04031, 04031, 04031, 04031) logged in
>   /oramisc01/oracle/diag/rdbms/gisp/GISP2/trace/alert_GISP2.log.

Comment: I see the alpha-numeric always in column 6 using the separator `;` did I miss something? (also doesnt look like 32 bit - can you hight light the number you need?)

Comment: `cut -sd ';' -f 1,6`?

Comment: Sorry, those are examples that I just quickly grabbed from the file, a lot of them (i.e D0C53D32C0EB3F85E0405C0A6FF002C9) do fall in the 17th column (32bit was a bad terminology to use, should have said 32 alpha-numeric string) but some have additional text prior to that column making it fall somewhere between 15th column and 19th column, just depends on the specific message that gets written to the OEM log.

Comment: Looking over some of the other suggestions as well, will need some time to read through and do some testing. Thanks for the really quick responses all!

Comment: melpomene - Thank you and yes that makes me feel pretty stupid not realizing that it was the 6th column when including the ";". That worked perfect. If I may...If I wanted to add for instance a couple other fields into the outputted file, would I just simply change the cut command to something like 
 
 
cut -sd ';' -f 1,2,4,6 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E -o "EST ;.{0,33}" file1| cut -d ";" -f2 > outputfile
```

you need to find a consistent "hook" which is "EST ;"

if you want this done all the time say on the minute, make a script and put in on crontab